# How to make column selection in Pipeline possible?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a toy dataset as the following:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector
from category_encoders.target_encoder import TargetEncoder

random.seed(2020)
K = 6
label = random.choices([1, 0], weights=[0.5, 0.5], k=K)
cat = random.choices(["A", "B"], k=K)
bird = random.choices(["C", "D"], k=K)
horse = random.choices(["E", "F", "G"], k=K)
n1 = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(K)]
n2 = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(K)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"cat": cat, 'bird': bird, 'horse': horse, 'n1': n1, 'n2': n2, "label": label})
```

[image]

### Goal

I would like to have all categorical features be either ordinal encoded or target encoded. For simplicity, which features to be encoded by which method is determined by the length of respective column names. What follows is a workable code to perform the function I need. In this code, I encode the categorical features of length longer than 4 with Target Encoding and leave the remaining categorical features to be ordinal-encoded.

```
THRESHOLD = 4
a = [x for x in filter(lambda x: len(x) > THRESHOLD, df.columns) if x not in ['label']]
b = [x for x in df.select_dtypes(exclude='number') if x not in a+['label']]

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('te', TargetEncoder(), a),
    ('oe', OrdinalEncoder(), b)
], remainder='passthrough')
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ct', ct)
])
pipe.fit_transform(df.drop(['label'], axis=1), y=df['label'])
```

The output is:

[image]

### Question

I am wondering if I can make a revision by substituting `ColumnTransformer()` with `Pipeline()` (`Pipeline` returns a Pandas DataFrame object while `ColumnTransformer` returns a numpy ndarray. And I want to work on the former in the early stage of my code). Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Also, I am wondering whether I can further streamline the pipeline by integrating the `a` and `b` lists (i.e. the dynamic selection of categorical features using a hyperparamter, THRESHOLD) into a pipeline.

Comment: Both .fit_transform() and .fit_predict() methods of Pipeline return arrays. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html  You can see this in your output as well. In your code above, wrapping the ColumnTransformer inside a Pipeline only makes sense if you are going to add other steps to your pipeline.

Comment: @KRKirov Thanks for pointing out the general cases. In my application, I have a custom made transformer that returns Dataframe, and I like it to work on a certain of columns only without using a ColumnTransformer() because I want the return of the output of the transformer after processing a subset of columns to be in the Dataframe format.